# keyboard reconfigure permanently

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

Recently upgraded to 18.04; I have a Sun Type 6 Keyboard (lots of useful extra keys such as Copy, Cut, Paste) and the installation configured it in an acceptable manner. A recent upgrade caused it to be reconfigured in a shambolic manner.

After much Googling, I found many suggested cures, all of which turned out to apply to other systems. Generally speaking, there are three ways to configure a keyboard

1. xmodmap - but this is now just a poor frontend to the xkb system
2. setxkbmap - which I believe to be a frontend to xkbcomp
3. xkbcomp

But all three suffer from the problem that their changes disappear on logout/login or on sleep/wakeup (and presumably hibernate as well). Also, it is recommended to construct a 'conf' file, but there are three formats for these, one to work with xorg.conf (which no longer exists), one to use with setxkbmap, and /etc/default/keyboard (which has miserable documentation, and does not appear to work anyway).

So here is my file clerew3.conf for setxkbmap:

```
Rules = "evdev"
Model = "sun-type-unix-usb"
Layout = "gb"
Symbols = "pc+gb+inet(evdev)+clerew"
```

Note that 'clerew' is a custom-tweak kept in /usr/local/share/X11/xkb/symbols (I don't like putting customized stuff under /usr). So I call this with

```
$ setxkbmap -I /usr/local/share/X11/xkb -option '' -config .../clerew3.conf -print
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+gb+inet(evdev)+clerew"};
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)" };
};
```

So the output looks good (apart from the geometry, which can wait), and if I put it into a file clerew.xkb I can compile it into a complete .xkb file wich indeed shows exactly what I wanted.

So now to compile it for use in the Display (which is :0, of course). So here is the 'official' way to do it (observe maximum verbosity set):

```
$ setxkbmap -v 10 -I /usr/local/share/X11/xkb -option '' -config /usr/local/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/clerew3.conf
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Found file /usr/local/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/clerew3.conf
After config file:
rules:      evdev
model:      sun-type-unix-usb
layout:     gb
variant:    ,
symbols:    pc+gb+inet(evdev)+clerew
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Warning! Multiple definitions of symbols
         Using config file, ignoring rules file
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      sun-type-unix-usb
layout:     gb
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+gb+inet(evdev)+clerew
geometry:   pc(pc104)
Error loading new keyboard description
```

So why the Error? I suspect it had trouble finding my customized 'clerew', in spite of the -I ... .

But I still had the 'clerew.xkb' file which had compiled corectly before with xkbcomp, so I compiled it again directly into :0 :

```
xkbcomp -I/usr/local/share/X11/xkb .../clerew3.xkb :0
```

and there it was! All my keys worked correctly: Libreoffice, Firefox, Thunderbird et al all understood my Copy/Cut/Paste etc, and so did any GTK aplication (with the aid of a suitable css file). Perfect!

Until I Slepped or Logged Out, whereupon it reverted to the shambolic keymap as before.

So that leaves two questions:

1. Exactly where does the system store the permanent keymap (presumably a .kvm file, though I looked for such a file in the root partition with 'find'). Is it in dconf (there is a smattering of xkb stuff in there, but I cannot see anything large enough)? Is it in xorg.conf (which doesn't exist anymore)? It has to be somewhere, because it keeps getting resurrected when I re-Login or Wakeup).
2. How do I cause it to be overwritten by the new version? My researches have turned up much advice , mostly applicable to other Linux Distributions, or earlier versions of Ubuntu. some suggest the use of localectl (with insufficient information how to use it); others mumble about dpkg-reconfigure (but I don't believe dconf is really involved); and some suggest running a script (such as my xkbcomp) in .profile, or .xinitrc or .config, or other dottish places (but I have verified that .profile does not work).

Help!

Comment: OK, more evidence. It seems that if Alice and Bob both have accounts (using the same physical keyboard), they can each configure it differently; so the config must be held in their Home space, but I still cannot find where. So at the moment Bob has setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      sun-type6-unix-usb
layout:     gb,gb
variant:    ,
options:    solaris:sun_compat
and can't get rid of that 'sun'compat', whereas Alice has three layouts (gb,us,gb) but her option is inet(evdev). Also, /etc/default/keyboard had layout sun-type-unix-usb and s/type/type6/ was seen by both of them.??